# UD decomposition in continuous-discrete kalman filter

Tags: linear-algebra, kalman-filter

My problem is basically this: you have a matrix A, positive semi-definite matrix P. Now, find matrix M such that:

$AP+PA^T=MPM^T$

why I need this? in the continuous-discrete Kalman formulation, where the covariance matrix updates like $\dot{P}=AP+PA^T+LQL$, I need to use a U-D factorization. And to do this, I need to convert it for a form of $MPM^T$

Answer (score 0):

When assuming that $P=P^\top\!\succ0$ then you can use
$$
M = \sqrt{A\,P + P\,A^\top} \sqrt{P}^{-1}.
$$
From this it follows that
$$
M^\top = \sqrt{P}^{-1} \sqrt{A\,P + P\,A^\top},
$$
so the two $\sqrt{P}^{-1}$ cancel with $P$ in $M\,P\,M^\top$, leaving only $A\,P + P\,A^\top$. Do note that $M$ can be a complex matrix and completely imaginary if $A\,P + P\,A^\top$ is semi-negatieve definite.

I did some testing and it seems to that you could also use
$$
M = \sqrt{\left(A\,P + P\,A^\top\right)P^{-1}} = \sqrt{A + P\,A^\top P^{-1}}.
$$
However, I did not find a proof that this is always true.